# Repeated ordered sequence search algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sequence, data-mining, dynamic-programming, bioinformatics

I have large ordered sequence of symbols, millions of symbols.
I have to find repeated ordered subsequences such that:

1. Search subsequences are unknown, I have to find subsequences that repeats elsewhere of large sequence.
2. Subsequences may have differences such as presence some amount of noise and absence of some symbols.

Not necessary condition:

3. Subsequences may have little amount of permutations of neighbor symbols.

The alphabet consists of thousands symbols.

Can you recommend well-known and well-studied algorithm for such task?

Comment: How are symbols ordered ?

Comment: how many basic patterns do you have ?

Comment: @igael, it is undefined.

Comment: @user3360241, The order is not random and not sorted.

Comment: Some examples would help. For example, if you have the sequence "abcdefgh <lots of stuff here> abcxefgh <more stuff>", would you consider `abcxefgh` a repeat of `abcdefgh`? After all, the `x` could be considered noise. Would `abcefgh` be considered a repeat? Just one symbol is missing. How long are the repeated subsequences you're looking for? What percentage of missing symbols or noise are you willing to tolerate?

Comment: Are you looking for something like the [BLAST](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=BLAST) algorithm?

Comment: it's better if you could provide a simple example about your question.

Comment: As others have stated, you should provide simple example. To begin with, you haven't specified criteria by which symbols are ordered, but you state that they are ordered.

Answer (score 0):

You can try aho-corasick multiple pattern matching and use a wildcard to search for substrings. For subsequence you want also the levenstein-distance. You can try my implementation in PHP of aho-corasick algorithm with wildcard at https://phpahocorasick.codeplex.com.

Comment: But he's looking for repeated subsequences in the sequence. He's not searching the sequence for all occurrences of a user-input pattern. Using the Aho-Corasick algorithm for this would require quadratic time. That is, given the sequence "abcdq9abxcdabcd", he would have to search for 'a', then for 'ab', then for 'abc', then for 'bc', etc. And that's not even taking into account the fuzzy pattern matching required to meet his second requirement.